# pypy interpreter does not recognize nosetests while pypy3 does

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, nose, pypy

I have written a script to test my Python library over different versions of python and pypy.
For pypy3,

```
python setup.py test
```

Works just fine.
But on pypy,
It runs `0 tests`. No failure, but zero tests.
Here is my script

```
language: python

matrix:
  include:
    - python: "pypy"
      env:
        - TEST_PY3="false"
    - python: "pypy3"
      env:
        - TEST_PY3="true"


before_install:

 - sudo apt-get update
 - sudo apt-get install build-essential

install:
  - if [[ "${TEST_PY3}" == "false" ]]; then
      pip install Cython;
      python setup.py install;
    fi

  - if [[ "${TEST_PY3}" == "true" ]]; then
      pip install Cython;
      python setup.py install;
    fi

script:
 - python setup.py test
```

I am using `nosetests`. This part of my `setup.py` might be helpful

```
test_suite         = 'nose.collector',
tests_require      = ['nose>=0.10.1']
```

Is there any problem of `nosetests` with `pypy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid `python setup.py install` for installation across different versions of python or pypy.

Prefer

```
pip install -e .
```